# Evaluate $\Delta z$ along the path $y=x^2$ from point $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given
>   $$ dz=xydx+xydy$$
>   Evaluate $\Delta z$ in going from point $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ along the path $y=x^2$.

I found out that

$ dz=xydx+xydy=\frac{1}{2}d(xy(x+y))$

$\Delta z=f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y)$

Should we put $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}$?

What will be the value of $x,y$?

I think $dx=1,dy=2xdx$

Is it correct?

How to complete the problem?

Comment: Check whether ${1\over2}d\bigl(xy(x+y)\bigr)=dz$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate along the specified path $y=x^2$ as follows,$$  \Delta z = \int_P dz $$
$$=\int_P (xydx+xydy )$$

$$=\int_0^1x^3dx
+\int_0^1 y^{3/2}dy$$